# Given prime ideal $P$ of ring $R$, does $RrR\subset P$ imply $r\in P$ for $r\in R$? (Hungerford)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, rngs

I am trying to understand a problem in Hungerford (p. 134, Exercise 14). Specifically, it says that if $P$ is a prime ideal in a not necessarily commutative ring $R$, and $r,s\in R$ such that $rRs\subseteq P$, then $r\in P$ or $s\in P$.

A hint is given: suppose that $RrR\subseteq P$, then $(r)^3\subseteq RrR\subseteq P$, and so $r\in (r)\subseteq P$.

But why is $(r)^3\subseteq RrR$?
I understand that $(r)$ contains $r$, since by definition it is the smallest ideal to do so.
If $(r)^3\subseteq RrR$ then $RrR$ contains $r$.
But since $RrR$ is the collection of finite sums of elements of the form $xry$, where $x,y\in R$,
I do not see why $RrR$ would contain $r$, in particular if $R$ is without a multiplicative identity.

Comment: Why do you think that $(r)^3\subseteq RrR$ implies $r\in RrR$? You do not generally have $r\in (r)^3$...

Comment: I thought that $(r)$ as a subring satisfies $(r)^3=(r)$, but it's actually $(r)^3\subseteq(r)$ (right?) Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Why would it satisfy $\langle r\rangle^3=\rangle r \rangle? You can only hope that if it contains an identity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that rings are not necessarily unital in Hungerford, so the ideal $(r)$ consists of elements of the form
$$nr + ar + rb + \sum_{i=1}^m a_irb_i\tag{A}$$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $m$ is a nonnegative integer, and $a,b,a_i,b_i\in R$.

Now, the thing is, the hint does **not** assert that $RrR$ contains $r$; the assertion is that it contains $(r)^3$.  Your claim that if $(r)^3\subseteq RrR$ then $RrR$ contains $r$ is unwarranted. It’s not even true in $\mathbb{Z}$ that $(r)^3$ contains $r$: $(2)^3=(8)$ does not contain $2$.

In order to contain $(r)^3$, given that $RrR$ is certainly closed under sums, it is enough that it contain any triple product of elements as above. And for that, it is enough that it contain any triple product of *summands* of the element above. This can be checked directly. For example,
$$(n_1r)(n_2r)(n_3r) = n_2\Bigl( (n_1r)r(n_3r)\Bigr)\in RrR.$$
Similarly,
$$(ar)(rb)(nr) = (ar)r(b(nr))\in RrR$$
and so on. Each term you get when you multiply out three elements of the form (A) is an element of $RrR$, and hence these products all lie in $RrR$, and hence the sums of products of that form lie in $RrR$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x,y \in R$ that do not lie in $P$,

We have $x(ry) \in P$.

By primality of P, it implies that x or ry is in P.

x isn't in P, it implies that ry must be in P and since y isn't in P as well, it is thus r.

It does conclude.

Comment: This is an argument for completely prime (or totally prime) ideals. A prime ideal $P$ is an ideal $P\neq R$ such that if $A$ and $B$ are ideals and $AB\subseteq P$, then $A\subseteq P$ or $B\subseteq P$. $P$ is totally prime if $P\neq R$ and whenever $rs\in P$ either $r\in P$ or $s\in P$. In a commutative ring the two definitions are equivalent. In a noncommutative ring, which is the case at hand, they are **not** equivalent. So this does not address the question given.

Comment: (nor does it explain why $rRs\subseteq P$ implies $r\in P$ or $s\in P$...)

Comment: I wasn't aware of this notion of prime ideal, my bad.

Comment: It’s not a “notion”. It’s *the definition*!